# How to block some files type and content while uploading in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I encountered a scenario i.e. where I have to stop uploading of .exe or .bat files when their extension is changed to acceptable extension (.txt,.rtf,.doc,.docx.xls,.xlsx,.pdf). 
I have tried to find a solution by using .NET code where I have used header codes of different file extensions, 
but header codes for .rtf get changed and doesn't seem to have a fixed header code. I have written below method. but that fails in case of .rtf since header code gets changed

```
private bool fileHeaderChking(HttpPostedFile Postedfile)
    {
        string[] arrayFileHeaderMagicNumber = {   "EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD-11-E0-A1-B1" , //doc
                                                  "7B-5C-72-74" ,   //rtf
                                                 "54-45-53-54" ,   //txt
                                                 "EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD-11-E0-A1-B1" , //xls
                                                 "50-4B-03-04" ,   //xlsx ,docx
                                                 "25-50-44-46" ,   //pdf
                                                 "EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD" ,  //jpg
                                                 "49-49-2A-00"                          //tif
                                              };

    string headerString = string.Empty;
    Boolean rtn = false;
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Postedfile.InputStream))
    {
        //get file header
        char[] headerBuffer = new char[4];
        byte[] Header = new byte[4];
        stream.Read(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
        Header = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(headerBuffer);
        headerString = BitConverter.ToString(Header);
        if (arrayFileHeaderMagicNumber.Contains(headerString.ToString()))
        {
            rtn = true;
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the mime-type using **urlmon.dll** which has an inbuild function i.e. **FindMimeFromData** called of the file for example :

The code for adding urlmon.ddl is as follows :

```
[DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]  
private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(System.UInt32 pBC,  
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,  
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,   
System.UInt32 cbSize, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,  
System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,  
out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,  
System.UInt32 dwReserverd);
```

and the code to check the mime is as follows:

```
HttpPostedFile file = FileUpload1.PostedFile;  
        byte[] document = new byte[file.ContentLength];  
        file.InputStream.Read(document, 0, file.ContentLength);  
        System.UInt32 mimetype;  
        FindMimeFromData(0, null, document, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);  
        System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);  
        string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);  
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);  

        if (mime == "application/pdf" || mime == "application/rtf")  
        {  
            // upload the File because file is valid  
            Response.Write("This is Valid File");  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            //  file is Invalid  
            Response.Write("This is Invalid File");  

        }
```

Comment: So ,will this work if somebody rename the .exe file to rtf and upload?

Comment: When i upload a rtf file then I get mime  as "aplication/octet-stream" and for rename exe with rtf I get mime as "application/x-msdownload". It's  not working.